# keyboard accessibility testing with dojo

Tags: unit-testing, dojo

We are making changes in our UI to make it KB accessible. So most of our changes lie in dojo HTML templates and dojo js files or in JSPs. 
We were looking into some kind of framework to create unit tests/ or tests that we could run each time to verify a11y changes are not broken. Something similar to server side unit tests - junit/testng.
We are heavily built on dojo 1.8. Any ideas? any tools or framework available that we can rely to build such tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first instance, I'd recommend Sitepen's Intern http://theintern.io/

Under the covers, this uses Selenium http://docs.seleniumhq.org/ for integration tests.

Selenium has support for targeting keyboard presses at specific elements, or just the active element.  See https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html and http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Send-Command-press-Tab-Button-961927.S.199307167